# SOAP request fails when using oracle Web Services Test Client

Tags: oracle, soap, wsdl, jdeveloper, webtestclient

I have a web services developed on Jdeveloper. When i test it using postman it works fine. But when i open oracle web services test client and try the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <faultcode>ns0:Client</faultcode>
                <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {http://myapp/ppp/}GetCustomerElement</faultstring>
            </ns0:Fault>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What can be the cause?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to call the SOAP service? Is your code mimicking everything that is set when using Postman (request body, HTTP headers, etc.)?

Comment: I am using Oracle web services Test client which opens in the browser and you fill the parameters in text box and it generates the SOAP message automatically.